# Can I safely delete old user folders in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, user-accounts, user-profile, deleting, safe-remove

I have a Windows Server 2003 machine. When I delete a user, their folder remains in the Documents and Settings. Is it safe for me to delete those folders if I don't need any of the data in there? Or will removing them cause other registry or system issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean local user profiles of users that have logged directly into the server itself. If you go into System Properties, go to Advanced then User Profiles, delete the old users from there and their Docs and Settings will delete as well.

Comment: But once I've deleted the user account, the profile no longer shows up there. There are a bunch of "Account Unknown"'s in the list though. Would those be the deleted accounts? I just need to remove those?

Comment: "Account unknown" is likely an account removed from Active Directory, and are generally safe to remove. You could open the Users folder, and kill an unknown, and you will see a named folder disappear.